# MAAS IP Change and IPMI problem

Tags: networking, juju, maas

Here is the case:

1) I had my MAAS Server and nodes in lab network

2) I mooed the server to operation ,so I changed the IP address of MAAS

3) I executed these:

 sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller

 sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller

 sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas

4) When I tried to power on ( start nodes) I got this:

Failed to query node's BMC — Node could not be queried node ... connection timeout

any suggestion for this case would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

1) I Uses static ip for IPMI and I updated the BIOS of servers.

2) After adding nodes again, everything worked!